# How to store data on an iOS web app?

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I'm currently working on a planning app, and I've ran into an issue. I can't find a way to store data without it being lost after restarting the app. I've tried cookies, window.name (despite the fact that that shouldn't even work to begin with), but neither of those work. The tasks (planned tasks) will be stored on the server, but seeing it's per person, having in input field for login everytime you start the app doesn't seem like the best plan. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using Localstorage?

Comment: @SinanSamet not yet — I'll look it up!

Comment: @SinanSamet that works! Thanks a million!

Comment: No problem glad it worked :)